# What is a #define string's type?

Tags: c++, types, registry

I think I am going about this wrong. I'm working on making a SO for a MSR type object. And by default (if I read it correctly) OPOS uses unicode. So I made my C++ automated class use unicode as well and from what I understand there is no way around it. In the OPOS head class there are 2 string definitions, the third one is one my creation:

```
#define OPOS_ROOTKEY "SOFTWARE\\OLEforRetail\\ServiceOPOS"
#define OPOS_CLASSKEY_MSR     "MSR"
#define OPOSMSR OPOS_ROOTKEY "\\" OPOS_CLASSKEY_MSR "\\"
```

This is so that a person can access the registry. So I decided to make myself a registry helper class instead of having it all in my SO. Looks like I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how I should do this in the end. I copied working code from another SO I had, but I feel that that code was not made correctly, and I want my code made right the first time.

So I came up with this, but I can not figure out how to combine my string with the class name. I made the class name as a parameter in my constructor.

```
RegistryHelper::RegistryHelper(LPCTSTR deviceName) {
    cout << "RegistryHelper::RegistryHelper()+" << endl;
    baseOpen = true;

    CString test;
    test.Format("%s%s",OPOSMSR, theClass); //fail
    REGSAM access = KEY_READ | KEY_WOW64_64KEY;
    LONG nError = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, theClass ,0, access,&hBaseKey); //not what I want, but would compile, I want test here instead of theClass

    if (nError != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        cerr << "(E)RegistryHelper::RegistryHelper(): Failed to load base key. [" <<(int)nError << "]" << endl;
        RegCloseKey(hBaseKey);
        baseOpen = false;
    }

    cout << "RegistryHelper::RegistryHelper()-" << endl;
}
```

Any tips on what I am doing wrong? since I'm on the subject: I'm going to post all my code for this. How bad is it?

What I'm after is something like this

```
unsigned int baud;
char* parity;

bool MSRSO::LoadRegistryValuesIntoMemory(LPCSTR deviceName) {
    RegistryHelper reg(deviceName);
    bool required = reg.LoadDWORD("BaudRate", 19200, baud);
    required = required && reg.LoadREGSZ("Parity", "NONE", parity);
    //other values
    reg.Close();
    return required;
}
```

Keep in mind I'm a C# and java guy so I may have my data types wrong. I only wrote simple hello world programs and temp conversion programs for myself in C++ on a SUPER old linux box back in the day. Although I am getting better at C++ I'm still not comfortable with it. So to sum up what is the data type of the #define type? How do I combine it with LPCTSTR? Should I have done that so that I can access registry values ONLY?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking the type of a string literal? That's `const char (&)[N]`. `#define`s do text replacement before compilation/

Comment: yeah but what is the data type? can I do LPCTSTR x = OPOS_ROOTKEY? or is it char* x = OPOS_ROOTKEY;

Comment: @RobertSnyder: It's literally text replacement, so the type is the implicit type of the literal.

Comment: You can assign it to whatever will take it. A `char[]`, a `std::string`, a `const char *`... `LPCTSTR` will only take it if `UNICODE` is not defined, in which case it's the same as `const char *`. If you're going the `TCHAR` route, you can wrap the identifier in the `TEXT` macro, which will convert it to the proper narrow/wide string type: `TEXT(OPOS_ROOTKEY)`

Comment: i'm so glad there are so many smart C++ programmers out there on the internetz. But now i feel stupid. So in my Control object it makes a call to msrdevice.Open("MSRNAME"); and so my registry values would be in OPOS_ROOTKEY\\OPOS_CLASSKEY_MSR\\MSRNAME. and that is what i'm trying to acheive, opening up that registry folder so i can get teh values from it... does what you say get me their? I hate feeling dumb :/

Comment: @RobertSnyder, If it's just the Unicode thing, `.Open(TEXT("MSRNAME"))` would make your argument `TCHAR`-compatible if that's what it uses. If it uses Unicode only, just pass `L"MSRNAME"`.

Comment: @chris unfortuantly the CO is wrote in C#, so i don't know that the TEXT bit applies.  Although i did switch a few things to TCHAR as suggested (don't know what TCHAR is) and so far it almost worked.. now i'm getting error C2308: concatenating mismatched strings

Comment: @RobertSnyder, `TCHAR` is a type that depends on whether `UNICODE` is defined or not. If it isn't `TCHAR` will be `char`, a narrow character. If it is, it will be `wchar_t`, a wide character. Likewise, `"abc"` is a narrow string, `L"abc"` is a wide string, and `TEXT("abc")` is one or the other, depending on `UNICODE`.

Comment: @chris That is AMAZING information. wow... thank you so much that helps me more than you know. I wish I would have known that earlier.. So basically i need to stop using char and start using TCHAR in here so that it is always right. Ugh... Thank you again!!!

Comment: @RobertSnyder, Glad I could help. Starting off in the Windows API is very frustrating in some aspects. At the beginning, you see very little relation to standard C++ due to all of the typedefs and everything, and must resort to C techniques that you might not be familiar with to use some functions. That's all on top of this whole `TCHAR` deal.

Comment: @chris could you do me a favor and submit your advice about the TCHAR as a answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has inconsistencies between narrow and wide strings. A literal `'a'` has the type `char`, and is a narrow character. A literal `L'a'` has the type `wchar_t`, and is a wide character.

Next, we can apply these to strings:
`"abc"` is a narrow string of type `const char (&)[4]`.
`L"abc"` is a wide string of type `const wchar_t (&)[4]`.

To reduce the hassle of supporting both, there is what is known as the `TCHAR`. Defined in a Windows header, this type is `char` or `wchar_t`, depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined. If it is defined, `TCHAR` will be `wchar_t`. If it is not defined, `TCHAR` will be `char`.

This also came with a `TEXT` macro that converts a string literal into characters of type `TCHAR`. That is, if `UNICODE` is defined, `TEXT("abc")` will be equivalent to `L"abc"`, and if it is not defined, `TEXT("abc")` will be equivalent to `"abc"`.

Strings were also given some typedefs as well:

```
LP[C][W|T]STR
```

The `LP` indicates a pointer, and the `STR` indicates "to a string". If `C` is included, the string will be a constant one. If `W` or `T` is included, the string will be made of characters of type `wchar_t` or `TCHAR` respectively.

For example:

```
LPSTR: char *
LPCSTR: const char *
LPWSTR: wchar_t *
LPCTSTR: const TCHAR *
```

Using this information, you can correctly understand why using `TCHAR` and `TEXT` will cause your code to become compatible with something else, whether it uses narrow or wide characters.

Here's a simple example, keeping in mind that `std::string` is, for our purposes, `std::basic_string<char>`:

```
std::basic_string<TCHAR> s(TEXT("abcd"));
s += TEXT("ZYXW"); //s is now `TEXT("abcdZXW")
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
#define OPOS_ROOTKEY "SOFTWARE\\OLEforRetail\\ServiceOPOS"
#define OPOS_CLASSKEY_MSR     "MSR"
#define OPOSMSR OPOS_ROOTKEY "\\" OPOS_CLASSKEY_MSR "\\"
```

to

```
#define OPOS_ROOTKEY L"SOFTWARE\\OLEforRetail\\ServiceOPOS"
#define OPOS_CLASSKEY_MSR     L"MSR"
#define OPOSMSR OPOS_ROOTKEY L"\\" OPOS_CLASSKEY_MSR "\\"
```

Comment: I can't change the first 2...but i can change the 3rd one since that is mine

Comment: You can change them also, don't worry L addition before string in C++ will make it unicode which is your problem

Comment: I didn't use the L, but it does now work with the TCHAR advice. I'll update the answer thank you for checking back with me.